# FullCalendar does not display events except in the current month

Tags: 7, javascript

I successfully got FullCalendar to work on a local test site (D7.26).  It worked great with events of this month, and I can even go to next month and return back in my view and now I don't get errors.  BUT when I make events for next month, the calendar will not show them when advancing to that month.  I don't get any errors as others reported, but I just get a totally blank month.  I can search for the events and sure-nuff, they're there in the database or list of events. It doesn't make any difference if I gave it an end date/time or not.  They all just will not show when I go forward to next month in my view.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm near the time that this site needs to go live.

Dave N

Answer (score 1):

My solution,
I switch in the view the 'contextual filter' the value 'when the filter values is NOT in the URL' from 'Provide default value' Type 'Current date' to 'Display all results for the specified field'.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have the same problem if views settings (advanced, other)  "Use Ajax" is set to yes.  if I change that to No, it seems to work fine.  Curiously, there is documentation on Drupal.org at https://www.drupal.org/node/1237808 where it says, "NOTE: if you're working with a big dataset it is advised to turn on the ajax setting."  This doesn't apppear to be correct.

Comment: If Ajax is not turned on, the module fetches ALL the matching events when the page is built regardless of date, and then, as you click through the months (or whatevers), does some Javascript stuff to only show the events matching the currently-selected month.  This is obviously not the Right Thing if you have a calendar with a few thousand events in it.  Anyway -- I'm having the same problem; has anybody had any luck figuring this stuff out?